# Codeigniter request control class

Tags: php, codeigniter, httpwebrequest, helper

i'm trying to do myself a good simple request control library.

this is my code:

```
class CI_Request
{
    public function isAjax()
    {    
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }

    public function isPost()
    {
        return isset($_POST);
    }

    public function isGet()
    {    
        return isset($_GET);
    }
}
```

but i don't know if i'm right.

any suggestions? :P

really thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your question is very vague.

You need to first understand tha Helpers and Libraries are two separate entities within the framework

> Helpers, as the name suggests, help
>   you with tasks. Each helper file is
>   simply a collection of functions in a
>   particular category. There are URL
>   Helpers, that assist in creating
>   links, there are Form Helpers that
>   help you create form elements, Text
>   Helpers perform various text
>   formatting routines, Cookie Helpers
>   set and read cookies, File Helpers
>   help you deal with files, etc.

And libraries is usually a class thats a collection of methods to handle a specific task, witch is why i think libraries are what your looking for.

You can create a library file within `application/libraries` of your application directory and create a file called `MyRequest.php`, the contents of that file would be like so..

```
class CI_MyRequest
{
   //..
}
```

The file name and the class name are relative so they must be the same, loading the library from a controller is simple

```
class Index extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->library->load('MyRequest');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->MyRequest->isAjax())
        {
            //.. Send me some json.
        }
    }
}
```

Note: haven't touched CI for long time so code may not be exact.

Comment: and in my controller i retrieve like you have explained ;)

Comment: maybe rename the library to `MY_MyRequest` in accordance to your configuration file .

Comment: i've renamed it into My_Request my library and trying to load it as'request' library but it still doesn't work :( really thanks anyway :(

Comment: look within your config as your library_prefix, it may bee `MY_` if it is and that class is named accordingly and the file is named accrodingly withn the libraries directory it should work fine